# I want to format any random dictionary according to this specified json format. The dictionary is generating dynamically

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

This is my dictionary:

```
my_dict = {"0": "age", "1": "Medu", "2": "Fedu", "3": "traveltime"}
```

---

I want dictionary in this json format:

```
var json = {
  columns: [{
      "0": "age"
    },
    {
      "1": "Medu"
    },
    {
      "2": "Fedu"
    },
    {
      "3": "traveltime"
    }
  ]
};
```

---

Also, I need it dynamic as the dictionary is also dynamic ...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dict()` constructor with a list comprehension:

```
>>> {"columns": [dict([item]) for item in my_dict.items()]}
```

or

```
>>> {"columns": [{k: v} for k, v in my_dict.items()]}
```

both will return

```
{'columns': [{'0': 'age'}, {'1': 'Medu'}, {'2': 'Fedu'}, {'3': 'traveltime'}]}
```

Comment: {'columns': [{'0': 'age'}, {'1': 'Medu'}, {'2': 'Fedu'}, {'3': 'traveltime'}]} , how  to change 'columns' to columns?

Comment: This is Python, not Javascript. Dictionary keys must be in quotes if they are strings.